# quadratic probing

Tags: computer-science

In the quadratic probing method for resolving hash collisions
H(k) =h(k) + c1*i^2 + c2*i.

I need some help figuring out how to decide values of c1 & c2 that is how to ensure that all the slots of the hash table are visited.

Answer (score 0):

Let ht_size = number of hash table slots. I assume you mean

```
h(k) + c1*i^2 + c2*i % ht_size
```

c1=0 and c2=1 will work ;)

c1=0 and c2 co-prime to ht_size also works. 1 is co-prime to any number. Prime numbers are also good candiates if ht_size is not accidentally the same prime number.

Why does such a setting visit all slots? 
If c1=0 and c2 is coprime to ht_size, then ggt(c2, ht_size) == 1.
In other words, in the group (algebraic group theory), c2 is a generator.
This means `c2**i` will generate all numbers from 0 to ht_size - 1.
By `**` i mean the power operator, i.e., applying the group's operator i times. The group's operator is `+`, thus `c2**i` in group theoretic notation corresponds to `c2*i` in normal notation.

I hope this gave you some idea how to start searching for a combination of c1 and c2 where c1 != 0.